# IE 11 throws error if object literal doesn't contain : How do I get around this?

Tags: javascript

The code below works great in all browsers except IE11.  In IE11 it throws the error, `Expected ':'`  How do I pass variables into a factory function if have to use a `:` after each key?  Thanks so much!

```js
'use strict';
 
var factoryCreature, zombie;

factoryCreature = function(species, actionOne, actionTwo) {
  return {
    species,
    actionOne,
    actionTwo,
    creatureStory() {
      console.log('The ' +this.species +' is about to ' +this.actionOne +' and ' +this.actionTwo +'.');
    }
  }
}
 
zombie = factoryCreature('Zombie', 'charge', 'bite');
 
zombie.creatureStory();
```

Comment: IE doesn't support ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well don't use ES6 object notation:

```
return {
  species: species,
  actionOne: actionOne,
  actionTwo: actionTow,
  creatureStory: function() {
     console.log('The ' +this.species +' is about to ' +this.actionOne +' and ' +this.actionTwo +'.');
   }
}
```

You may use *babel* or sth similar to automate this.

Answer (score 1):

IE11 doesn't have full ES6 support. Specifically for the object literal shorthand.
http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions

Specifically I would just switch to the longhand.

```
{ a:a, b:b}
```